# Maximum value from column while rows have different fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I wrote following sql query

```
SELECT  ST.Roll, CR.Code, CR.Title, CR.Credits, SCH.ObtainedGPA, SCH.Grade
FROM [MIU_UCAM.1.0.1].[dbo].[StudentCourseHistory]  AS SCH
JOIN [MIU_UCAM.1.0.1].[dbo].[Student] AS ST ON SCH.StudentID = ST.StudentID
JOIN [MIU_UCAM.1.0.1].[dbo].[Course] AS CR ON SCH.CourseID = CR.CourseID AND SCH.VersionID = CR.VersionID

WHERE ST.Roll ='0914BPM00387'
```

It return result like following

```
Roll            Code    Title                          Credits  ObtainedGPA  Grade

0914BPM00387    BPM216  Physiology Lab -                   1    4.00         A+
0914BPM00387    BPM217  Pharmaceutical Microbiology        3    2.25         C
0914BPM00387    BPM217  Pharmaceutical Microbiology        3    2.00         D 
0914BPM00387    BPM218  Pharmaceutical Microbiology Lab    1    3.50         A-
```

Here BPM217 and BPM217 are same but it's ObtainedGrade is different, 2.25 and 2.00 and Grade is also different, C and D. Now how can I get only the column hat have maximum value 2.25.

Comment: sql? mySQL or MSSQL or PLSQL ?

Comment: What about a simple where? `WHERE SCH.ObtainedGPA <= 2.25` This gets all the columns where the ObtainedGPA is of maximum 2.25

Comment: But I need 2.25 value column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
SELECT ST.Roll, 
     CR.Code, 
     CR.Title, 
     CR.Credits, 
     (select MAX(SCH.ObtainedGPA)
          from StudenCourseHistory s
          where s.StudentID = ST.Student_ID
          and s.CourseID = CR.CourseID),
     SCH.Grade
FROM [MIU_UCAM.1.0.1].[dbo].[StudentCourseHistory]  AS SCH
JOIN [MIU_UCAM.1.0.1].[dbo].[Student] AS ST ON SCH.StudentID = ST.StudentID
JOIN [MIU_UCAM.1.0.1].[dbo].[Course] AS CR ON SCH.CourseID = CR.CourseID AND SCH.VersionID = CR.VersionID

WHERE ST.Roll ='0914BPM00387'
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using `MAX` on the `ObtainedGPA` and `MIN` on the `GRADE`:

```
SELECT  ST.Roll, CR.Code, CR.Title, CR.Credits, MAX(SCH.ObtainedGPA), MIN(SCH.GRADE)
FROM [MIU_UCAM.1.0.1].[dbo].[StudentCourseHistory]  AS SCH
JOIN [MIU_UCAM.1.0.1].[dbo].[Student] AS ST ON SCH.StudentID = ST.StudentID
JOIN [MIU_UCAM.1.0.1].[dbo].[Course] AS CR ON SCH.CourseID = CR.CourseID AND SCH.VersionID = CR.VersionID
WHERE ST.Roll ='0914BPM00387'
GROUP BY ST.Roll, CR.Code, CR.Title, CR.Credits
```